# Can we change Key's value of Json data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json, html

I have retrieved JSON data content of a web page and want to use it in app.

One of the key's value contain data with "\n and commented out lines". I want to remove them and use only simple text information.

I can't put my code because the "commented line" are not visible here.

Here is a demo:

```
{"content":"Hello \n 'CommentedLinesHere' \n how are you? " }
```

So, is there any way to get “Hello how are you?” here?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: see below. The code has been updated and now removes all commented text between `\n`

Comment: @Paul my str is empty now

Comment: did you run the demo below? it is removing all text between `\n`. Is this not what you want?

Comment: Thanks for your help @paul. I have got an idea to make things work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the global flag from regex to globally replace your char and then turn it back into a JSON object

```
var noNewLines = JSON.stringify(myJson);
noNewLines = noNewLines.replace(/\n/g, "");
var backToJson= JSON.parse(noNewLines );
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a regex to replace all the `\n` newline characters with a blank space. See the code below:

```js
var obj = {"content": "Hello \n 'CommentedLinesHere' \n how are you? "}
var str = obj.content.replace(/\n(.|\n|\r)+\n/g, "");
alert(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var objJsonData = {"content":"Hello \n 'CommentedLinesHere' \n how are you? "}
    var ResultJson = objJsonData.content.replace(/\n/g, '').replace("CommentedLinesHere",'').replace("'",'').replace("'",'');
    alert(ResultJson);
```